# Label eqnarray split and align

Tags: math-mode, alignment, eqnarray

I've this tex code

```
\begin{eqnarray}
&\partial_{t}f =D \nabla^{2}f -f (1-f)[(1-s)-(2-s)f]\epsilon          \label{eqn:1}\\ \nonumber
&\\ 
\text{from which we get}
&\partial_{t}f =- \frac{\delta F}{\delta f} \\  \nonumber
&\\ 
\text{where f is} 
&F=\int dx \big[ \frac{1}{2} D (\partial_{x f^{2}})+ V(f)\big] \\     \nonumber
&\\ 
\text{and} 
& V(f) \equiv \int df f (1-f)[(1-s)-(2-s)f]\epsilon \\ \nonumber
&\\ 
&\hspace{0.8cm}  \equiv \frac{1}{2}f^{2}-\frac{1}{3}(3- 2s)f^{3}+\frac{1}{4}(2-s)f^{4}
\end{eqnarray}
```

[image: the output is :]

I would like to have a label for one of these equations; I tried with align and split but I couldn't make them aligned.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! 1) Don't use `eqnarray`, it yields  bad spacing, 2) I can't deduce from the above image what you want to align, 3) which line(s) do you want to label?  4) Must all lines be numbered?

Answer (score 2):

Does one of those options is what you looking for?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[66]
    \begin{align}
&&  \partial_{t}f   
    & = D \nabla^{2}f -f(1-f)[(1-s)-(2-s)f]\epsilon
                    \label{eqn:1}                   \\ 
&\text{from which we get}  
    & \partial_{t}f  
    & = -\frac{\delta F}{\delta f}                  \\  
& \text{where $f$ is} 
    & F
    & = \int dx \big[ \frac{1}{2} D (\partial_{x f^{2}})+ V(f)\big] \\
& \text{and}
    & V(f) 
    &   \equiv \int df f (1-f)[(1-s)-(2-s)f]\epsilon  \\
    &&& \equiv \frac{1}{2}f^{2}-\frac{1}{3}(3- 2s)f^{3} + \frac{1}{4}(2-s)f^{4}
    \end{align}
or better is to use \verb+\shortintertext{...}+ defined in the package \verb+mathtools+:
    \begin{align}
\partial_{t}f
    & = D \nabla^{2}f -f(1-f)[(1-s)-(2-s)f]\epsilon
                    \label{eqn:1}                   
\shortintertext{from which we get}
\partial_{t}f
    & = -\frac{\delta F}{\delta f}                 
\shortintertext{where $f$ is}
F   & = \int dx \big[ \frac{1}{2} D (\partial_{x f^{2}})+ V(f)\big]
\shortintertext{and}
V(f)& \equiv \int df f (1-f)[(1-s)-(2-s)f]\epsilon          \\
    & \equiv \frac{1}{2}f^{2}-\frac{1}{3}(3- 2s)f^{3} + \frac{1}{4}(2-s)f^{4}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: yes thanks! the last one using "use \verb+\shortintertext{...}+" doesn't work, but the previous it's fine :)!

Comment: @io_gucci, the second example doesn't work? Do you test my MWE as it is? What error message you receive?

Comment: the error is : Undefined control sequence. <argument> ...ilon \label{eqn:1}                   
\shortintertext{from which we get}
\parti... l.167 \end{align}

Comment: @io_gucci, do you have installed `mathtools` package? I tested my answer again and it works (i upload result obtained with this test). Please test my MWE as it is. If it not works, than you have some mismatch in your LaTeX installation.

Comment: now it's perfectly working! so sorry I was sure to have that package! dankuwel :D